# How to assign var as a part of an other var in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, dos

How to assign var as a part of an other var in a batch file?

Im trying that but is not working:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET VAR1 = Value1
SET VAR2 = %VAR1%AndOtherThing
ECHO %VAR2%
```

Result: echo is off
Expected result: Value1AndOtherThing

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SET VAR1= Value1
SET VAR2= %VAR1%AndOtherThing
ECHO %VAR2%
```

don't put spaces in front of the equals.

Comment: You probably don't want spaces after the equals either, unless you explicitly want your VAR1 value to be " Value1".